# Prevent SocketIO from reconnecting, once a successful connection has been established with a different address

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm building some small tool for SocketIO testing. The first thing the user needs to do, is to supply an address to connect to.

Once the user has submitted the address, this function is fired:

```
connect = (address) => {

    socket = io(address);

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected!')
    });

    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
      console.log('Error connecting!')
    });
  }
```

Notice that "socket" is a global variable.

The problem starts if the user supplies an invalid address. SocketIO would keep reconnecting, and wont stop even if a successful connection has been established **using a different address**(if the user corrects the address and submits it).

Even though the variable "socket" gets a new instance assigned to it, the old one somehow persists in the background, carrying out its reconnection attemps.

How could i manually prevent the reconnection, or completely "destroy" the old instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may [.disconnect()](https://socket.io/docs/client-api#socket-disconnect) your "old" instance just before it gets reassigned:

```js
connect = (address) => {
    if (socket) {
        socket.disconnect(); // <==== !!!
    }

    socket = io(address);

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected!')
    });

    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
      console.log('Error connecting!')
    });
  }
```

*Just make sure variable `socket` was initialized before this function is ever called, e.g:*

```js
const socket = null;
```

This should work absolutely fine.